# NodeJS Download HTML with Request

Tags: node.js, request

Having quite a bit of trouble getting an HTML page to download using NodeJS. Here is my code snippet:

```js
const request = require('request');

request('http://www.google.com', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { 
        return console.log(err); 
    }
    console.log(body.url);
    console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

When I step through this it executes in about half a second. I get no errors back but I'm not getting any content logged to the console...

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
const request = require('request')

request('https://google.com', (err, res, body) => console.log(err ? err : body))
```

With request you can pipe the response body of a request directly to a `WriteableStream`

```
const fs = require('fs')
const request = require('request')

request('https://google.com').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./google-index.html'))
```

Per the comments below, the following example illustrates how to wrap this request so it can be awaited and printed to the screen or written to a file.

```
const {promisify} = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile)
const request = require('request')

const getGoogleIndexHTML = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request('https://google.com', (err, res, body) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(body))
    })
}

const printAndWriteGoogleIndex = async () => {
    try {
        let googleIndexHTML = await getGoogleIndexHTML()
        console.log(googleIndexHTML)

        await writeFile('./google-index.html', googleIndexHTML, 'utf8')
        console.log('google-index.html written.')
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

printAndWriteGoogleIndex()
```

Comment: Just tried it, but nothing printed out to the console... Also tried to print out the results with fs, and the page is just empty. No html at all...

Comment: I tested both of them and they both work. Make sure you're using `https` and don't use the `json` flag.

Comment: 'Make sure you're using https' - Can you explain a bit more here?

Comment: @JoshuaHoward actually, just tested `http` and `https` and they both worked. Not sure whats up with your environment that this code doesn't work. Aside from the use of request, `fs` is part of Node Core and `createWriteStream()` is not a new function by anymeans. Are you running my code exactly as on its own?

Comment: Okay so I broke just that chunk out into another script and that worked okay. I think the problem might relate to the fact that I'm using NickJs and I'm making calls inside of an async function...

Comment: @JoshuaHoward added an example wrapping the above code with `async`. Hope this helps.